# django issue while running manage.py runserver

Tags: django

I have made changes in View.py and URL.py file and getting 
" Unresolved reference 'Django' less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspection info: This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Top-level and class-level items are supported better than instance items. is  it a serious error

```
en
```

---

Performing system checks...

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper
 at 0x0362D6F0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\malvi\Envs\book-django\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreloa
d.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\malvi\Envs\book-django\lib\site-packages\django\core\management
\commands\runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\malvi\Envs\book-django\lib\site-packages\django\core\management
\base.py", line 364, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\malvi\Envs\book-django\lib\site-packages\django\core\management
\base.py", line 351, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\malvi\Envs\book-django\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\reg
istry.py", line 73, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\malvi\Envs\book-django\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\url
s.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\malvi\Envs\book-django\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\url
s.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\malvi\Envs\book-django\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.
py", line 397, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\malvi\Envs\book-django\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functiona
l.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\malvi\Envs\book-django\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.
py", line 536, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\malvi\Envs\book-django\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functiona
l.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\malvi\Envs\book-django\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.
py", line 529, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\malvi\Envs\book-django\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in
 import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\python_programs\book\book\urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
AttributeError: module 'django.views' has no attribute 'index'
```

Comment: Share the *full* traceback as well as the (relevant parts of the) files where you made changes to.

Comment: views.py file    from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.


    def index(request):
        return render(request ,'stores.views.index')                                                  url.py  urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^$', 'store.views.index')

Comment: [edit] the question.

Comment: how to add trace as this page was saying too long character

Comment: It is too long when you [edit] the question (not commenting), but clicking the link here and changing the question)?

Comment: i have used django 2 also so that there will not be any issue regarding version

Comment: Did you by any chance performed *two* imports of `views`? It looks like you also imported `from django import views`, so you have *overridden* the `views`. variable.

Comment: That being said, by sharing your `urls.py` (or at least some relevant parts), we can probably help you in a better way.

Comment: Show us `urls.py`

Comment: from django.conf.urls import url


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^$', 'store.views.index')
]        but again when i saw views.py file it was showing django as                        from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.


    def index(request):
        return render(request ,'stores.views.index')  ,,, unresolved reference when i hover over django

Comment: i dont understand why django unreferenced coming again and again .

Comment: i have removed virtual env folder and installed django 2.1.1 with python 3.7 ,, but still getting below error in url.py ......url.py file attatched below .

Comment: urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^bookstore/', include(bookstore.urls)),
]

Comment: i have found the solution ,, what i did i have created two urls.py file ..one in main folder and other in app folder .it works !!!!!